# How to select an edge in Photoshop CS6 that is not quite horizontal or vertical?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I'm using Photoshop CS6 on a Macintosh and have created a layer mask and wish to erase at the edges of a painting in a photograph, but the edges are not quite true, so even after doing a perspective crop on the photo, the edges are not quite all straight.  I would like to select a straight line that follows the edge and draw upon it in the layer mask.  I've been using the selection tool and the `Single Row Marquee Tool` and `Single Column Marquee Tool` together with the shift key to add lines and option key to remove lines. In this way as I work my way along the line, drawing on the selected part in the layer mask, I add or remove columns or rows as needed. Using the `Quick Selection Tool` or `Magic Wand` do not work well as I don't get very sharp edges and in some cases the background is too close in color to the edge.

There must be a way to draw a straight line that is not quite horizontal or vertical.  How can I do this more easily in Photoshop CS6?

Comment: The **Polyagonal Lasso Tool**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Scott, the the `Polygonal Lasso Tool` allows you to select the vertices of a polygon region to select, allowing the edge to be easily selected.